# Url from google: \75, reg exp

Tags: regex

I have such part of the code, which i'va got from google:

```
"
\u0438", '/webmasters/tools/backlinks-latest-dl?
hl\75ru\46siteUrl\75http://site.comt/\46security_token\75sMuiouiouWA-
TiuoiuoiuiocDo4:1489898898'); </script></div>
"
```

- `\75 is '='` but is it 16 digit? Why google don't use `'base64'` or `'urlencode'`
- When i use such regexp

`/backlinks-latest-dl.*security_token\\\75/`

everything is ok. 
But when i put the code to the file and then parse the file- i can't find data by the reg exp. I can find using only

```
/backlinks-latest-dl.*security_token(\\\)(75)/ HERE 3 '\' NOT 2
```

When i use

```
/backlinks-latest-dl.*security_token(\\\75)/
```

it is'n't work.
What is it?

Comment: Try to add what you are attempting? Why is the \75 character relevant from RegEx perspective? What are you trying to use the url for (or the information within it)? And what do you mean by "everything is ok" when you use the regexp? Have you tried using an online regextester like https://regex101.com/ ? If you get it to work there, then please link it here, so we can tell what you mean by a success.

Comment: @karthik manchala: Why was the information about 2 and 3 backslashes removed from the question?

Comment: Deleted by mistake.. edited! nice catch thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I could hardly get your point but the problem could be that you put three backslashes instead of two or four. It you want to escape the initial slashes,you should use four of them in a row \\. Or, you need to leave only two of them if additional escaping is not needed. I just don't see any logic in using three backslashes.